# DAO solidity contract, how to destribute voting rights?

Tags: solidity

I`m developing a DAO contract on the ropsten testnet with solidity. As with all DAO contracts, people can contribute to the contract and receive the relative amount of tokens based on their contribution.

After the administrator of the contract creates proposals, the token holders can vote on a particular proposal and they should do so with the weighted vote which is proportional to the number of **tokens they hold / total supply of tokens**.

This is where I run into some trouble trying to figure out the right way to assign a weighted vote system, so that contributors with more tokens have greater weight to their vote.

For example, if the total supply is 100 000 000 tokens and the first contributor has 1000 tokens that would make him a 0,00001 % shareholder, but the problem is that solidity doesn`t work with decimals so I would have to somehow normalize the shareholder % to a number between **1 - 100** to assign it to the vote weight of that contributor.

What are ways to build a weighted vote system for such DAO contracts ?

Comment: You don't need to use "decimals", or any other type of "proportional resolution" for that matter (most certainly not percentage-based, which yields a huge loss of accuracy). The total supply is fixed, so just pass the balance of each user as "the weight" of that user.

Comment: And even if the total supply was a dynamic value, you could still handle it, by saving two values instead of one (the user's balance and the current total supply). You need to do the math only at the point where you calculate the final voting decision. Only then, do you lose some accuracy upon division. You should aim to postpone the division operation as far back towards the end of the computation, in order to make it as accurate as possible (i.e., lose as little accuracy as possible).

Comment: Yes, obviously I was over-complicating the whole thing, never thought of just using the contribution amount as a vote-weight and it should only be relative to the whole contribution amount,  not the total supply of tokens . I guess when looking at a particular problem too long you miss the most logical solution...Thanks 